# how to find ESX/ESXi machine manufacturer and model from virtual machine

Tags: vmware-esxi, virtual-machines, vmware-vsphere, vmware-esx

Using command prompt when running this : 'systeminfo | find "System"` in a physical machine, it's giving the Manufacturer and model,

```
System Manufacturer:       Dell Inc.
System Model:              Latitude 7300
```

By running same command in Virtual machine, will it possible to get ESX/ESXi machine's Manufacturer and model?

It's giving me VMware details only,

```
System Manufacturer:       VMware, Inc.
System Model:              VMware Virtual Platform
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no way to get the actual hardware information from within a VMware VM.

You can only get this information by querying the hypervisor directly.

Comment: OK.  Thanks.  Could you please guide with some article on querying the hypervisor

Comment: The SDKs and APIs are [well documented](https://www.vmware.com/support/pubs/).

Comment: VMware pyvmomi api can be helpful. The following sample extract host information:
https://github.com/vmware/pyvmomi-community-samples/pull/225/files
In addition, you can just connect to ESXi host via ssh from your vm and use esxcli. Might help: https://www.vmwareblog.org/cool-vsphere-command-line-interface-esxcli-commands-helped-lot/